# Multiple Typescript modules without duplicate identifier errors

Tags: typescript

I have split a project in to multiple bower modules all of which need to reference underscore.d.ts file

```
- bower_components
 |- module_a
    |- src
       |- externl-commonjs.ts
 |  |- typings
 |     |- underscore
 |- module_b
    |- src
       |- externl-commonjs.ts
    |- typings
       |- underscore
- src
  |- externl-commonjs.ts
- typings
  |- underscore
```

I can successfully compile module_a and module_b on their own... but when they are in a project like above I get Duplicate identifier errors because of the multiple `/// <reference`s to underscore.d.ts within each external module file.

How would you work around this and have a single source of truth for underscore.d.ts.

Comment: are the two references the same path (literally identical)?

Comment: and I think you should may try something with import.

Comment: all underscore.d.ts files are the same

Comment: Unless they reference the same exact `d.ts` file, I'd expect the error you're receiving. Both modules need to reference the same (physical) file.

Comment: thanks, that's what i'm finding... I've had to manually reference d.ts files in each project.

Comment: That's a known problem with d.ts files (tsd) and bower, they don't have something like shared "dependencies". I hope that some will solve this issue soon.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by using https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-dts-bundle which will create a d.ts from all the internally required code but doesn't directly link to any external definitions.

You can then reference the created bundle in the top level project and individually reference any other type dependencies manually.

Answer (score 0):

The way I got around this was to use `///<amd-dependency path="foo" name="foo">` and then `declare var foo;` 
to get the amd module in my project (which is what I want the most) and not have the Tsc jump the wire and get into duplicate identifier hell. They will fix that eventually, but what I want most is to check out my sub-project and compile it in the context of my parent project. Once I am safely in AMD, I am ok.

It is also cool to chain your grunt ts tasks together, using grunt-exec. This way, I can do a watch on my parent project for ts, and kick off the ts task in the child project.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this same problem. A real pain. 
How I solved it was:

1. don't include typings in module a & b. Only include the top-level one.
2. In your top-level source file ( externl-commonjs.ts), at the top, add the /// reference  to typings.   As that file include other .ts files, they'll pickup the /// reference

Some great background articles:

1. http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/03/28/ambient-type-definitions-duplicate-identifier-typescript-fix/
2. http://ivanz.com/2016/06/07/how-does-typescript-discover-type-declarations-definitions-javascript

It looks like TypeScript 2.0 added a "typeroots" section to tsconfig to help with this. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html